# Angular Set Controller and routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm using routeProvider to set the controller and a route param when my application is configured. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
        when('/person/:uuid/report', { controller: 'CandidateCtrl' }).
        when('/person/:uuid/confirm', { controller: 'ConfirmCtrl', }).
        when('/person/add', { controller: 'AddCtrl' })
}]);
```

However, the controller is not being set correctly. Additionally, when I set the controller with ng-controller in the page itself, the routeParams object is empty. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

I've also tried this, which also isn't associating the controller with the page nor setting the route-params.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
        when('/person/:uuid/report', { controller: 'CandidateCtrl', template: 'templates/report.html' }).
        when('/person/:uuid/confirm', { controller: 'ConfirmCtrl', template: 'templates/confirm.html'  }).
        when('/person/add', { controller: 'AddCtrl', template: 'templates/add.html'  })
}]);
```

Here's the controller that I'm testing this out with:

```
appController.controller('CandidateCtrl', ['$routeParams',
        function($routeParams) { 
    console.log($routeParams);
}]);
```

Comment: What do you mean *not set correctly?*

Comment: Why you didn't specify templateUrl attribute while configuring routes?

Comment: @ tymeJV: I mean that the controller isn't associated with the page - it's not pulling any of the appropriate information.  @SatyamKoyani, I have tried that, updates have been made to the question.

Comment: can you please make a fiddle or share snippet of your controller ?

Comment: @cscan Your controller snippet will help us to guide in your problem. Post some controller snippet

Comment: @SatyamKoyani Updated to include the controller. It's simply logging the routeParam so I know that everything's wired up correctly.

Comment: Are you hitting URL's like -> #/person/123/report-> here 123 stands for your whatever uuid?

Comment: That's correct, the URLs that I'm using are as follows: http://localhost:8080/person/123ab-c/report  I'm using that UUID to grab information from a restful interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add templateUrl

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/person/:uuid/report', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/CandidateCtrl.html', //TODO : replace with the good template
    controller: 'CandidateCtrl'
  }).
  when('/person/:uuid/confirm', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/ConfirmCtrl.html', //TODO : replace with the good template
    controller: 'ConfirmCtrl'
  }).
  when('/person/add', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/AddCtrl.html', //TODO : replace with the good template
    controller: 'AddCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: 'Something' //TODO : replace with the good url
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was serving the views by via my web-mvc. I've since changed it to serve a layout and have the partial pages be kept in the resource folder.